# When is figures placement relevant?

Tags: floats

I wonder when the automatic placement of figures is relevant as it totally breaks the document in the following example (note the last sentence of the introduction):

[image]

So is it better to force placement with `[H]` option so it stays at the right place?

Comment: Why do you include an equation as a figure???

Comment: Even if you must for some unknown reasons include it as image instead of writing it directly in latex, don't place it in a figure environment. This will also prevent it from floating away.

Comment: @samcarter I want to put it in a figure because I won't directly talk about it in the text, it's just a reminder for the readers, isn't it a good idea? (Also this equation is not complete, there will be some text in the figure to explain the different variables involved)

Comment: If you don't talk about it, don't put it in your document. If you want it in your document, talk about it - even if you just slightly adjust your last sentence and mention that the equation follows. The problem is just that an equation is not a figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see why you want to add an equation into a figure ...

To place the figure you have two possibilitys:

Do not use floating `figure` environment like:

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{An example image}
\label{fig:test}
\end{center}
```

See that you need to use `\captionof` to get an caption ...

The second possibility is to use floating environment `figure` and use option `[hb]` to "force" a placement here or at the bottom of the page:

```
\begin{figure}[hb!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\caption{An example image 1}
\label{fig:test1}
\end{figure}
```

The complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\section{introduction}
\blindtext
See~\ref{fig:test}.

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{An example image}
\label{fig:test}
\end{center}

\blindtext
\section{Section 2}
See~\label{fig:test1}
\begin{figure}[hb!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\caption{An example image 1}
\label{fig:test1}
\end{figure}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

gives you:

[image]